# How to send data and images from android simultaneously via php

Tags: android

before I ever send data and images with success, but it was done with two different procedures

this is my code to send data

public class HTTPPostData extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String Result = "";
        byte[] Bresult = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL_TO_LOAD);
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = LPD;
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Bresult = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
                Result = new String(Bresult, "UTF-8");
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return Result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        if (!result.toString().trim().equals("")) {
            RunProcedure.StrParam = result;
            RunProcedure.run();
        }
    }
}
```

and this my code to transfer pic

```
public boolean TransferFileToHttp(String address_to_handle, String file_name) {
    boolean result = false;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = file_name;
    String urlServer = address_to_handle;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                pathToOurFile));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                        + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Exception handling
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

how to joining transfer file procedure to post data procedure and retrieve string as a result?

Comment: Your title says "...via php"? I don't see any php related content in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to do so. However, you will have to perform some additional steps.

You will first have to convert the image to a base 64 string. Refer to this document 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Now the string can be sent as regular json data.

On the server end, you will need a mechanism to convert back the base64 string to image. It is a trivial task though.

There are some disadvantages of this method such as huge size of json request and additional overhead of encoding/decoding.

Comment: What is best approach to do so?

Comment: What you are currently using is a good approach. To resolve the issue with upload confirmation, what you can do is, upload the images first and then json. Your json should have path of images and php should validate those to make sure images are in place. For additional confirmation, you can also use md5 hash of images.